# TypeError: images.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I have a shopping cart and I have products with a different photo,
I need to show the photo in the loop, but my code doesn't work, could you help me, please?

```
import React from 'react'
import Builder from '../Control/Builder/Builder'

import './Control.css'

const images = [
    { names: require('../../assets/Tshirt.jpg') },
    { names: require('../../assets/shoes.jpg') },
    { names: require('../../assets/pwbag.jpg') },
    { names: require('../../assets/perfume.jpg') },
    { names: require('../../assets/mbag.jpg') },
    { names: require('../../assets/womenbag.jpg') }
]

const Control = (props) => {
    return (

        <div className="flex-container">
            {products.map((item) => {
                return <Builder
                    photo={images.map((item) => {
                        return item.name
                    })}
                    price={item.price}
                    add={() => props.addProduct(item.id)}
                />
            })}
        </div>

    )
}

export default Control
```

Comment: Where does `products` coming from? `images` doesn't have `item.name` attribute.

Comment: return item.names

Comment: I do that, but it doesn't work yet

Comment: @Dennis Vash: I delet it for now just in stackoverflow

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Dennis Vash: Thank you, I deleted it because stackoverflow doesn't permission for write that part of my code

Comment: Check type of `products`, probably it is not type of array.

Answer (score 1):

return `item.names` instead of `item.name` from map method.

Why?

If you look at the `images` array, it has objects with property `names` instead of `name`. So inside map callback you should be accessing `item.names`.